# How to use pandas to delete rows and columns on multiple sheets in a workbook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have a file `input_file_new.xsl` and I need to deleet all completely empty rows and columns. I have come up with this function:

```
def DeleteEmptyColumns(filename):
    import pandas as pd
    new_loc = `input_file_new.xsl`
    df = pd.read_excel(new_loc, 'Person')

    df.drop('Application_ID', 1,inplace=True)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

Which does delete the columns correctly, but only on the first sheet and then it saves that sheet as a whole new worksheet. I need each sheet to remain on the same document after I remove all empty columns. Is there an easier way? I looked into Win32 COM but I want to be able to use Pandas for this.

EDIT: this is a screenshot of the excel. So you can see on the Person tab I need to delete column A because it is completely empty. I need to do this for each tab.[image: excel doc]

Comment: To me it's not clear what the problem is. You want that  the columns are removed from all the sheets?

Comment: I need to remove all empty rows and columns from each sheet

Comment: Okay, and then store this in a new file or override each sheet in the original file?

Comment: Either one will do

Comment: with empty you mean containing only Nans?

Comment: for columns, its empty if its empty strings in every cell and same for rows

Comment: When you read the table with pandas the empty cells are filled with Nan values

Comment: So how can I edit each sheet of a workbook and save that workbook in pandas? I see no examples of that anywhere

Comment: Can you edit your question and include an example of the table contained in one sheet of your workbook? this would help me to understand your situation

Comment: yes I added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
df = pd.read_excel("input_file_new.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name=None)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
for key in df:
    sheet= df[key].dropna(how="all").dropna(1,how="all")
    sheet.to_excel(writer, key,index=False, header=False )
    
writer.save()
```

The for loop is used to iterate over each sheet in the workbook. Then the columns and rows that contain only cells with "Nan" are removed and the resulting table is stored in a sheet called as the original one but in a new file.

`read_excel` with `sheet_name` set to `None` will read each sheet of the workbook into a dictionary (called df).